# Bond price rearrangement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I rearrange:
$$
P=\cfrac{C}{(1+y)^n} +\cfrac{M}{(1+y)^n}
$$
Into this:
$$
P=C\left[\frac{1-{\cfrac{1}{(1+y)^n}}}{(y)} \right]+\cfrac{M}{(1+y)^n}
$$

Sorry I couldn't get (y) as the denominator of this expression in equation format but it is: $$\left( 1-{\cfrac{1}{(1+y)^n}} \right)$$

Comment: That's only true for $n = 1$.

Comment: So assuming n=1 what would be the steps in order for me to rearrange the original expression into the second expression algebraically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

A coupon bond is defined by cashflows occuring in n periods and matures at period n.

Thus $$P = \frac{C}{(1+y)} + \frac{C}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{C}{(1+y)^3}+\cdots\frac{C}{(1+y)^n}+\frac{M}{(1+y)^n}$$

$\frac{1}{(1+y)}\leq 1$.  Using the summation formula $A_n = \frac{(1-a^n)}{1-a}$

$$P = \frac{C}{1+y}\cdot\dfrac{1-\cfrac{1}{(1+y)^{n}}}{1-\cfrac{1}{(1+y)}}+\cfrac{M}{(1+y)^n}$$

If you simplify the bottom, you will get your result which is

$$P = C\cdot\dfrac{1-\cfrac{1}{(1+y)^{n}}}{(y)}+\cfrac{M}{(1+y)^n}$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Can you show me how you simplified?

Comment: Let us say 1/(1+y) = a, Taking C out as it constant, then you will have $a+a^2+a^3+...a^n = a(1+a+a^2+a^3+...+a^(n-1) = a(1-a^n)/(1-a)$  Now substitute the value of a as 1/(1+y).  You should research into the summation formulahttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: When you simplify the complex fraction after the geometric progression to solve for (y) in the denominator what steps did you use to simplify? Sorry if this is an elementary question but I have a hard time understanding the process of simplifying complex fractions.